# How to execute a script using crontab

Tags: bash, shell, cron, execute

I'm trying to execute a particular script located in /logann/myFile through crontab file.

I've already tried a lot of ways but no one makes any results.

I add in crontab file this line to call my script

26 10   * * *   root    cd /logann && ./apagar_temp_tomcat

(The time I change to test)

And my script is

#!/bin/sh

rm /tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp/*.tmp

rm /tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp/*.xml

I just want to execute this script. This script will delete every .tmp/.xml files in the folder tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp.

Any ideas?

Thank you guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cron` jobs will run in their own shell. So you can't expect to see `tedvs` on your console.

Try to write something in file, for example

```
* * * * * echo tedvs > file_in_your_directory.txt
```

Comment: Hmm, I get it. Actually, echo was just a test. I really want to execute those commands to delete these files                                                                                                    rm /tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp/*.tmp
rm /tmp/tomcat7-tomcat7-tmp/*.xml

Comment: Sorry, It worked well here, the problem was that I was testing with Echo and as you said, cron runs in other shell. That's why I was thinking it was wrong. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just make one function in file and call that file or function in cron as per your time interval.
I did this in PHP

```
shell_exec(\'(crontab -l ; echo "* * * * * curl www-data http://localhost/sp/delete.php") | crontab -\');
```